# How to display distinct column values into different column and values of different columns in a single column?

Tags: oracle, concatenation

```
DAY       PERIOD     YEAR   SEC      TeacherID

Monday         1        3     C         100010
Monday         2        3     C         100011
Tuesday        1        3     C         100011
Tuesday        2        3     C         100010


Display for TeacherID 100010

Period      Monday     Tuesday
     1         3,C         
     2                     3,C
```

Help me or correct me if you think I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To get this output you can use [pivot](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php) operator:

```
select * from 
  (select day, period, year||','||sec ys from test where teacherid = '100010')
pivot (max(ys) for day in ('Monday' as Monday, 'Tuesday' as Tuesday))
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ad35/1)

This works Oracle 11g version. For older versions you can use this syntax:

```
select period, 
    max(case when day='Monday' then year||','||sec end) Monday, 
    max(case when day='Tuesday' then year||','||sec end) Tuesday 
  from test 
  where teacherid = '100010'
  group by period order by period
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ad35/2)

Comment: I hope so. And if you want to add teachers to output (you didn't mention that)  just add `teacherid` to the list of fields in subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you need something like that:

```
select period, 
case day 
when 'Monday' then year||sec
else ''
end "Monday",
case day 
when 'Tuesday' then year||sec
else ''
end "Tuesday"
from test_tbl
```